# What is an appropriate silkscreen pattern for upright through-hole diodes?

Tags: pcb, diodes

I'm currently using this:

[image: diode]

as a pattern to indicate a through-hole diode with anode touching the top pad and cathode in the air.

1. Is there a more standard way to indicate this?
2. Is there a standard as to which orientation is preferred for upright diodes? The only thing I've found on the internet is a [lead-forming company](https://masline.com/lead-forming) which shows both options ("band-up" and "band-down").

Comment: That looks good to me. It's clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Is the way you've drawn it - meant to have the short lead going to ground and the long lead to +5 V?  Might it be better the other way round so there is less opportunity to short out the supply?

Comment: @DDuck Yes, your description of the orientation is correct. As for whether it's better to have "more exposed ground" vs. "more exposed 5v"... I guess?

Comment: That's as good as anything.  Just as a general comment, if you're so space constrained you're standing up through-hole components, it's time to learn how to deal with surface-mount.

Comment: @TimWescott One reason to want such set up is to have the option to quickly cut off the component with a plier. Or simply because the component doesn't exist in SMD version (e.g. high voltage + high current)